# HTML simulate textarea with div container

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I want to create a little WYSIWYG editor. 
The idea:
First I want to add the feature to write and change text. So I add an onClick and onKeyBoard Listener to my div container. When I click the div I set a varaible named "focused" to true. When an key event is fired I check if focused is true. In case focus is false nothing will happen else the new charater will be added on the cursor's position.

My questions:
Is this the right way? I tried to check how other editors handle the text input but I wasnt able to get it.

In case this is the right way - how can I simulate a blinking cursor. In a textarea the cursor will blink but who about a div container? The cursor will hide immideatly after clicking.

Comment: Why won't you use the textarea element ?

Comment: Have you tried using Ckeditor?

Comment: Can I place HTML tags in a textarea? I want to create my own little editor - I dont want to use a finished one.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) which is a great editor.

Comment: seems like just figuring out where in the source code to look for something simple like "how to simulate a blinking cursor" would be a project in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this for fun/practice.  If you're doing this for professional reason then I HIGHLY recommend you don't reinvent the wheel and use something like [Ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

That being said; you need to look into [event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial#Events_and_Scripts).  Specifically, for your question about focusing, you can look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection).  The way you're describing (setting a variable to true/false) seems like it is going to just run into problems.  If you use the standard events attribute (as opposed to setting a "focus" variable onclick) you should define functions to execute and then set them as an [onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onfocus)/[onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur) attribute for the element you're listening to.

That is if you aren't using a javacript library like mootools, jquery, extJS, etc.  If you're using one of those they likely have their own way of handling events, so you should search their respective documentation for how to implement event handlers.

One more note; you really should be using a textarea over a div (unless I'm misunderstanding and you just want to do something when a user focuses on your div).  If you're using javascript only to completely reinvent a texteditor from a div; then your web page will not function without javascript.  If you keep the text area; users could still type information in and you still get the benefit of grabbing text contents for form submits but using divs means your web page will just be rendered useless without javascript.